# How to calculate gravitational force?

Tags: java

I am getting the wrong output for the code below.  G = 6.674 x 10^-11.  I am supposed to get 3.559466666666664e+22 but I am getting 8.0088E44.  Can someone please explain what I have wrong on my code?  I will appreciate it. The inputs are 2e30 6e24 1.5e11

```
import stdlib.StdOut;
public class GraviForce {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double m1 = Double.parseDouble(args [0]);
    double m2 = Double.parseDouble(args [1]);
    double r  = Double.parseDouble(args [2]);
    double G = 6.674e-11;
    double f = G * (m1 * m2) / r * r;
    StdOut.println(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple operator associativity mistake - missing parens:

```
double f = G * (m1 * m2) / (r * r);
```